# Bitmap Factory animation using threads or async task

Tags: android, multithreading, animation

This question is a follow up on multiple question's that I asked on this forum on why an animation that I have been trying is not working.

Just a brief on the previous questions:

1. My animation works as an individual project of 2 classes, but will not work
    when included in my project containing multiple classes.
2. All activities leading up to my animation activity were closed using "finish()" class
3. The app never closes or freezes, the animation just doesn't play, but the intent occurs
    and the next activity opens/displays successfully
4. First used 10 images each of 70-80 kb size for the animation and later used, 
    10 images of 30 - 34 kb size each and still got the same effect.

I have since come to the conclusion that my main thread may be doing excessive work, and this may be the reason why the animation is not occurring properly.

Thus using 2 threads I coded the following sequence, but still am getting the same result. 
Can some one please explain what is going on and why can't I get a simple animation working???

my ButtonAnime class

```
public class ButtonAnime extends Activity{

private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 500;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);         
        final AnimationDrawable animate= new AnimationDrawable();           
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iVArcRail_2);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {   <---- thread 1

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                 options.inSampleSize = 24;
                 options.inPurgeable = true;
                 options.inScaled = true;

                  Bitmap b;
                     Drawable d;

                    int i =5;
                    b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ab1, options);
                    d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b);   
                    animate.addFrame(d, i);
                    b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ab2, options);
                    d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b); 
                    animate.addFrame(d, i);
                    b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ab3, options);
                    d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b); 
                    animate.addFrame(d, i);
                    b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ab4, options);
                    d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b); 
                    animate.addFrame(d, i);
                    b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ab5, options);
                    d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b); 
                    animate.addFrame(d, i);
                    b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ab6, options);
                    d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b); 
                    animate.addFrame(d, i);
                    b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ab7, options);
                    d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b); 
                    animate.addFrame(d, i);
                    b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ab8, options);
                    d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b); 
                    animate.addFrame(d, i);
                    b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ab9, options);
                    d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b); 
                    animate.addFrame(d, i);
                    b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ab10, options);
                    d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b); 
                    animate.addFrame(d, i);
                    imageView.setBackground(animate);
                    imageView.post(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    animate.start();   
                                }

                            }); 
        }

        });

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {  <-- thread 2

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this , Home.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                System.gc();
            }
        }, 50);
    }

}
```

log cat following use of anime_loading.. during the button click for loading of animation

```
 GC_EXPLICIT freed 10K, 1% free 27351K/27444K, paused 6ms+7ms, total 71ms
 GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6098K, 22% free 23220K/29404K, paused 125ms, total 126ms
 GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 15% free 25169K/29404K, paused 185ms, total 189ms
 GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 27118K/29404K, paused 215ms, total 218ms
 GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 29068K/29404K, paused 139ms, total 140ms
 Grow heap (frag case) to 30.367MB for 1995856-byte allocation
 Clamp target GC heap from 32.367MB to 32.000MB
 GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 31017K/31356K, paused 235ms, total 235ms
 Clamp target GC heap from 32.368MB to 32.000MB
 GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 31018K/31356K, paused 232ms, total 233ms
 Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1995856-byte allocation
 Clamp target GC heap from 32.368MB to 32.000MB
 GC_BEFORE_OOM freed <1K, 2% free 31018K/31356K, paused 290ms, total 290ms
 Out of memory on a 1995856-byte allocation.
 "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
    | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xb3a90c90 self=0xb8f64380
    | sysTid=1723 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=-1225301676
    | state=R schedstat=( 5530000000 8170000000 2275 ) utm=486 stm=67 core=0
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:575)
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:410)
 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
 at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
 at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:282)
 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2092)
 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
 at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
 at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
 at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
 at com.example.thomas.anime.Button_Anime.onCreate(Button_Anime.java:21)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
 D/AndroidRuntime(1723): Shutting down VM
  threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a8fb90)
```

log cat for error msf that occured while using anime_loading

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.thomas, PID: 1723
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.thomas/com.example.thomas.anime.Button_Anime}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
  E/AndroidRuntime(1723):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
 at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
 at com.example.thomas.anime.Button_Anime.onCreate(Button_Anime.java:21)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
 ... 11 more
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
 ... 24 more
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:575)
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:410)
 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
 at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable     
 at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:282)
 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2092)
 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
 at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
 at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
 ... 27 more
```

Comment: if your images are packed into the application, why not create an animation list, instead of decoding the bitmaps at runtime ?

Comment: sorry for late comment but did this already.. atleast in this case the intent works.. while using using xml the app crashes... @LenaBru

Comment: what is the reason the app crashes?

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html#start()

Comment: i keep loosing my net connection forgive me.. the  problem was outofmemory exception @LenaBru

Comment: how big are your images?

Comment: please try my solution - note i do not call "start" i call "setVisible(true,true)"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of decoding the resources at runtime, why not create an animation list like this:

goes into the anim folder

anim_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false" >

<item
android:drawable="@drawable/animation1"
android:duration="@integer/frame_animation_time_ms"/>
<item
android:drawable="@drawable/animation2"
android:duration="@integer/frame_animation_time_ms"/>
<item
android:drawable="@drawable/animation3"
android:duration="@integer/frame_animation_time_ms"/>
<item
android:drawable="@drawable/animation4"
android:duration="@integer/frame_animation_time_ms"/>
<item
android:drawable="@drawable/animation5"
android:duration="@integer/frame_animation_time_ms"/>
<item
android:drawable="@drawable/animation6"
android:duration="@integer/frame_animation_time_ms"/>

</animation-list>
```

This goes inside the layout

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/myImageView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@anim/anim_button" />
```

This is the code to run it

```
private void animateImageView() {

AnimationDrawable imageViewAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
imageViewAnimation.setVisible(true, true);

}
```

Comment: sorry for late comment.. but i tried xml first.. the app kept crashing.. thats why i switched over to dynamically loading the images in the animation ... @LenaBru

Comment: what is the reason the app was crashing?

Comment: i tried this (xml)... but still the project is crashing.. i am uploading the latest log cat that was generated during use of anime_loading.xml @LenaBru

Comment: can you change your animate.start() to animate.setVisible(true,true) ? if you read the android javadocs, you will see they advise against calling start in onCreate(), but setVisible(true,true) does work in oncreate. Also i did not see any logs from you

Comment: i did change  animate.start() to animate.setVisivble() exactly  like u mentioned in ur answer.. thanks to my net problem, it takes time to load things from here sorry .. but the logs are visible now.. @LenaBru

Comment: can you give me your set of images, i want to try this myself?

Comment: it works as an individual project.. ie 2 classes, 2 activities, there is no problem.. animation works like a charm.. but when included in my project which has up till now 10 classes 15 activities it is crashing.. (its used as an animation upon a button click in home screen) i can give u the images no problem but u do understand the problem right?? @LenaBru

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56059/discussion-between-user3214173-and-lena-bru).