# iterate a thread/handler/timer 10 times

Tags: android, multithreading, loops, timer, handler

i want to iterate a thread 10 times..

```
 for(final int i: list)<-- problem
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask timertask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                imageView.setBackgroundResource(i);
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(timertask,200);  
    }
```

this code does that but eclipse recomends/insists on the i being final..

thus only last image is being displayed.. is there any way i can iterate this such that all images are displayed and timer can run correctly???

also **pls dont recomend animation**.. it has completely failed.. thats why i am resorting to this...

Comment: "also pls dont recomend animation.. it has completely failed.. thats why i am resorting to this..." this is NOT the correct way of running an animation. It probably failed because you didn't know how to do it properly. This (whenever you manage to make it work), will have a very poor performance.

Comment: @Budius could u answer this question pls?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341876/bitmap-factory-animation-using-threads-or-async-task/24342006?noredirect=1#comment37647913_24342006

Comment: yes. You won't be able to do that. You're trying to do something that is simply too "expensive" for a MOBILE PHONE to do. As you can see, on every possible attempt of yours, you're running out of memory. That's the lead you should follow. How big are those images? 120-150kb (you said on the conversation), so I'll guess around 800px, which is around 2.6MB when the system decompresses them, times 16 photos you said on the conversation thread, it will be 40MB just for the images! NO! It will not work! Maybe you should try a video file instead?

Comment: that was done by LenaBru not me.. i was trying to run 10 images each of size 8kb and it was failing... @Budius

Answer (score 2):

To fix your code you could just use a local variable

```
for(int i: list)<-- problem no more
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timertask = new TimerTask() {

    // create a final variable and assign it to i
    final int x = i;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(x);   // then use it here
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timertask,200);  
}
```

Comment: quick question.. in the above code will the image be kept in memory or will it be discarded after every iteration of the loop??? @codeMagic

Answer (score 1):

Simply copy the value of `i` in a `final` variable:

```
for(int i : list) {
    final int value = i;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timertask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(value);
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timertask,200);  
}
```

Comment: quick question.. in the above code will the image be kept in memory or will it be discarded after every iteration of the loop??? @Vakh